# MySQL 5.6 SELECT UNION Query

Tags: select, union, mysql-5.6

The SELECT UNION query below functions as needed.
We want to display different columns from the same table and same entry as separate rows.
I know there has to be a better / cleaner way.
Please advise.

```
SELECT task1 AS Job FROM prevent WHERE task1 != "" AND eq = ? AND id = ? AND pmTask LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT task2 AS Job FROM prevent WHERE task2 != "" AND eq = ? AND id = ? AND pmTask LIKE ?
UNION
SELECT task3 AS Job FROM prevent WHERE task3 != "" AND eq = ? AND id = ? AND pmTask LIKE ?
```

Here is a snapshot of the db entry displayed below.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is the actual best way of doing it.

In MySQL 8.x you could use a CTE to simplify the code, but since you are using 5.6, I don't see a better option.

To be brutally honest, your database model is not that great. It will support a fixed/maximum number of tasks per job since their are included as columns of the table rather than as 1:n relationship with another table. This design will generate a lot more work, every time you need to store and retrieve data from it. Unfortunately, unless you change your model, there's little you can do to improve those queries.

**EDIT AS OF Jan 29, 2020:**

From your description, jobs and tasks seem to be two different entities. If that's the case, instead of using a single table to store both of them it's advisable to use two.

For example:

```
create table prevent (
  id int primary key not null,
  eq int,
  eqName varchar(50),
  timeFrame int,
  pmTask varchar(50)
);

create table task (
  prevent_id int primary key not null,
  task_number int,
  name varchar(100),
  constraint fk_task_job1 foreign key (job_id) references prevent (id)
);

insert into prevent (id, eq, eqName, timeFrame, pmTask) 
  values (910, 910, 'Boiler', 90, 'Boiler Quarterly Check');

insert into task (prevent_id, task_number, name) values (910, 1, 'job work tasks');
insert into task (prevent_id, task_number, name) values (910, 2, 'check oil levels');
insert into task (prevent_id, task_number, name) values (910, 3, 'belt tension');
```

Then your query would be:

```
select
  t.task_number,
  t.name
from prevent j
join task t on t.prevent_id = j.id
where t.name <> '' 
  and j.id = ?
  and j.pmTask like ?
order by t.task_number
```

Comment: I'm such a rookie when it comes to database design.  I appreciate all suggestions.  I don't know what 1:n relationship means.   Can you explain further.  Thanks

Comment: @PaulMc I added the example about splitting your single table into two, using a 1:n relationship. This way, you can store hundres (or millions) of tasks per job, and the query remains of the same size.